# Исключение по адресу в программе на ассемблере

Tags: ассемблер, исключения

Мне нужно написать программу на ассемблере х64 в VS 2017, Windows 10.
Нужно ввести в окошко строку, а программа должна заменить * на пробелы и вывести в строку результат.

Пример нашей преподавательницы запускается, но при нажатии на кнопку RUN происходит исключение по адресу.

Не знаете, в чем проблема? Сама она тоже не знает. Код ниже. 
Заранее спасибо.

```
ExitProcess PROTO 
DlgProc PROTO :QWORD,:QWORD, :QWORD, :QWORD
PostQuitMessage PROTO
GetModuleHandleA PROTO
DialogBoxParamA PROTO
GetDlgItemTextA PROTO
SendDlgItemMessageA PROTO

include windows.inc

.data
DName db "dial",0
hinst dq ?
result_buffer db 20 dup ("0")

hwnd dq 0
uMsg dq 0
wParam dq 0
lParam dq 0

.code
main proc
 sub rsp, 56

 mov rcx,0
 call GetModuleHandleA 
 mov hinst,rax

 mov rcx,hinst
 lea rdx, DName
 mov r8,0
 lea r9,DlgProc
 mov     dword ptr [rsp+32], 0
 call DialogBoxParamA
 mov rcx,0
 call ExitProcess 
 main endp

DlgProc proc q:QWORD,w:QWORD, e:QWORD, r:QWORD
  cmp edx, WM_CLOSE ;10h   
  je Exit_Button

  cmp edx, WM_COMMAND   ;111h   
  je go_button
  jne End_it 

 go_button:
 cmp r8,4
 je Exit_Button
 cmp r8,3
 je next
 jne End_it

 next:
    mov hwnd,rcx
    mov uMsg,rdx
    mov wParam,r8
    mov lParam,r9

    mov rdx,1
    lea r8,result_buffer
    mov r9,20
    call GetDlgItemTextA

    mov rcx,  hwnd
    mov rdx,  uMsg
    mov r8,   wParam
    mov r9,   lParam

        mov hwnd,rcx

    mov rcx,rax
    lea rsi,result_buffer
    m1:
     cmp byte ptr [rsi],'*'
     je m2
     jne m3
     m2:
      mov byte ptr [rsi],' '
     m3:
      inc rsi
     loop m1    

        mov rcx,hwnd

    mov rdx,2
    mov r8,LB_DELETESTRING  ;  182h - LB_DELETESTRING
    mov r9,0
    lea rsi,result_buffer
    mov qword ptr [rsp+32],rsi 
    call SendDlgItemMessageA

        mov rcx,  hwnd
        mov rdx,  uMsg
        mov r8,   wParam
        mov r9,   lParam

    mov rdx,2
    mov r8,LB_ADDSTRING  ;  182h - LB_DELETESTRING
    mov r9,0
    lea rsi,result_buffer
    mov qword ptr [rsp+32],rsi 
    call SendDlgItemMessageA
    jmp End_it

Exit_Button:
    mov rcx,0
    call PostQuitMessage

End_it:    
    mov rax,0
    ret
DlgProc endp 
end
```

Файл RSRC.RC

```
dial DIALOG 0, 0, 309, 95
CAPTION "mY dialog"
BEGIN
    EDITTEXT 1, 48,7,222,14
    ListBox 2,48,24,222,14
    PUSHBUTTON "Run", 3, 167,41,50,14  
    PUSHBUTTON "Exit",4, 220,41,50,12
    LTEXT "Input string:", -1, 7,10,40,8    
END
```

Ошибка в отладчике:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Нужно запустить в отладчике и смотреть, что там происходит перед выбросом исключения.

Comment: Попробуйте закомментировать `call DialogBoxParamA`. Есть среды, которые подсвечивают не *текущую* строку, а ту, что *будет* выполнена.

Comment: @Arhad, Тогда ничего не происходит, пишет готово и все

Comment: @Arhad, судя по вопросу, диалог появляется, значит проблема не в DialogBoxParamA, а скорее всего внутри процедуры-обработчика.

Comment: @IvanMelobensky, совет по поводу запуска программы под отладчиком все еще актуален (пока я не найду простой способ установить 64-битный масм без необходимости установки VS 2017 целиком, или пока не перепишу ваш код под fasm, и в итоге сам не запущу его под отладичком).

Comment: При вызове `call GetDlgItemTextA` вы забываете заполнить регистр `rcx` (являющийся параметром `hDlg`). Может быть, в этом дело?

Comment: @Arhad Пожалуйста, можете немного конкретнее сказать, что мне изменить в коде? Просто я еще не до конца разбираюсь в ассемблере, 1 курс)

Comment: Перенесите `mov hwnd,rcx` в начало функции, а на его старом месте впишите `mov rcx,  hwnd` (да, мы восстанавливаем `rcx` и до, и после вызова `GetDlgItemTextA`). Если не поможет  — надо ждать @insolor.

Comment: И ещё, зачем вы постоянно сохраняете `rdx`, `r8` и `r9`? Вы же всё равно не используете аргументы `uMsg`, `wParam` и `lParam`. А вызывающая нас сторона уже позаботилась о том, чтобы сохранить их для себя.

Comment: @Arhad, тут все сложно. Кое-как переделанный под 64 бита 32-битный пример для flat assembler, запускается, но не реагирует на кнопки и на закрытие через крестик, а найденные Microsoft C++ Build Tools зачем-то хотят 8 Гб места на диске и на текущем этапе установки зачем-то создают точку восстановления системы. В общем, это надолго.

Comment: @insolor, надеюсь, что эти 8 гигов занимает отборнейшая база примеров и документации, а не мини-операционная система...

Comment: Спасибо вам большое за попытки помочь) Давно хотел сюда написать, да все никак)
Эту ошибку не смогли исправить на 2017 студии ни преподаватель, ни весь 1ый курс. 
Вроде бы заработало на Windows 7 + VS 2010.
Но на 2017  и 10 винде ни в какую.

Comment: Выложите, пожалуйста, собранную программу. Ассемблера у меня нет, но есть дизассемблер :)

Comment: @Arhad дело в том, что заработало на 2 компьютерах  из целой лаборатории в университете. У меня же на ноуте 10 винда и 17 студия. А подробностей, при которых заработало, не знаю. Такие дела)

Comment: Друг сказал, что не меняли в коде ничего перед запуском в универе. Просто заработало и все. Но учитель попросил все же добиться работы в комбинации вин 10 + студия 17. Да и самому интересно, профессия же будущая :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В коде две проблемы, приводящих к вылетам:

1. Не проверяется что введена пустая строка (значение, возвращенное из `GetDlgItemTextA`, равно нулю), из-за чего при первом попадании на инструкцию `loop` 0 в регистре `rcx` превращается в -1, получаем "бесконечный" цикл и попытку записи за пределы секции данных.
2. В начале процедуры `DlgProc` нужно выделить на стеке место под параметры процедуры `SendDlgItemMessageA`, при выходе из `DlgProc` стек восстановить. Из-за того что это не выполнено, скорее всего при выполнении `SendDlgItemMessageA` (которое происходит только при нажатии кнопки "Run") происходит затирание каких-то данных вызывающего кода, при выходе из процедуры происходит вылет.

Вот рабочий код, адаптированный под fasm, с моими замечаниями:

```
include 'win64a.inc'

format MS64 COFF

public main

extrn PostQuitMessage
extrn SendDlgItemMessageA
extrn GetModuleHandleA
extrn GetDlgItemTextA
extrn DialogBoxParamA
extrn ExitProcess

section '.data' readable writeable

DName db "dial",0
result_buffer db 20 dup ("0")

section '.code' code readable executable

main:
    sub rsp, 5*8  ; место под 5 параметров для вызова DialogBoxParamA
    mov rcx,0
    call GetModuleHandleA

    mov rcx, rax  ; [hinst]
    mov rdx, DName
    mov r8, 0
    mov r9, DlgProc
    mov dword [rsp+32], 0
    call DialogBoxParamA
    mov rcx,0
    call ExitProcess


proc DlgProc hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam
    ; место под параметры на стеке выделено как раз для того,
    ; чтобы можно было сохранить там значения тех же параметров из регистров
    mov [hwnd], rcx
    mov [uMsg], rdx
    mov [wParam], r8
    mov [lParam], r9

    sub rsp, 5*8  ; резервируем на стеке место под 5 параметров для вызова SendDlgItemMessageA

    cmp edx, WM_CLOSE ; 10h
    je Exit_Button

    cmp edx, WM_COMMAND ; 111h
    je go_button
    jne End_it 

    go_button:
    cmp r8,4
    je Exit_Button
    cmp r8,3
    ; je next ; лишняя проверка 
    jne End_it

; next:
    mov rdx,1
    mov r8, result_buffer
    mov r9,20
    call GetDlgItemTextA

    ; Не нужно постоянно гонять параметры между памятью и регистрами
    ; mov rcx,  hwnd
    ; mov rdx,  uMsg
    ; mov r8,   wParam
    ; mov r9,   lParam

    ; mov hwnd,rcx
    test rax, rax  ; не забываем проверить, что введена не пустая строка
    jz End_it

    mov rcx, rax
    mov rsi, result_buffer

m1:
    cmp byte [rsi], '*'
    ; je m2  ; лишняя проверка
    jne m3
; m2:
    mov byte [rsi], '+' ; заменяю на +, чтобы была заметнее разница
m3:
    inc rsi
    loop m1

    mov rcx, [hwnd]
    mov rdx, 2  ; ListBox
    mov r8, LB_DELETESTRING  ; 182h - LB_DELETESTRING
    mov r9, 0
    mov qword [rsp+32], result_buffer ; mov qword ptr [rsp+32], offset result_buffer для masm
    call SendDlgItemMessageA

    ; mov rcx,  hwnd
    ; mov rdx,  uMsg
    ; mov r8,   wParam
    ; mov r9,   lParam

    mov rcx, [hwnd]
    mov rdx,2
    mov r8, LB_ADDSTRING
    mov r9,0
    mov qword [rsp+32], result_buffer
    call SendDlgItemMessageA
    jmp End_it

Exit_Button:
    mov rcx,0
    call PostQuitMessage

End_it:
    mov rax,0

    add rsp, 5*8  ; восстанавливаем стек

    ret
endp
```

Для компиляции нужен [fasm](http://flatassembler.net/), а также GoRC и GoLink (см. [The Go tools for
Windows + Assembler](http://www.godevtool.com/), к языку Go не имеют никакого отношения). Для отладки использовал [x64dbg](http://x64dbg.com).

Собственно, компиляция:

```
fasm dialog.asm
gorc /machine X64 rsrc.rc
golink dialog.obj rsrc.res user32.dll kernel32.dll /entry main
```

Ну и наконец скриншот (состояние после ввода текста и нажатия на кнопку Run):

[image: Скриншот]

P.S. "криво расставленные котлы" авторские, rsrc.rc я в неизмененном виде взял из вопроса.

Comment: Большое человеческое спасибо! От души просто!

Comment: Сейчас только придется сидеть и переделывать код для вижуал студии)

Comment: @IvanMelobensky, в вашем коде по идее достаточно поправить выделение памяти в стэке под параметры и проверку на пустую строку, то что я в начале писал.

Comment: @IvanMelobensky, ну или если возьметесь переводить, то основные особенности такие: получение значения переменной в fasm в квадратных скобках, в masm без них (`mov rcx, [hwnd]` == `mov rcx, hwnd`), получение адреса переменной - в fasm просто по имени переменной, в masm - через offset и имя переменной (`mov rsi, result_buffer` == `mov rsi, offset result_buffer`). Ну и `byte` == `byte ptr` и `qword` == `qword ptr` и т.д.

Comment: Ст**е**к только.

Comment: @0andriy, заменил.